# Word for someone who keeps a group in good shape?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can mean a person who keeps a group in good shape? For instance, this person (also a member of the group) makes sure group members are turning in their work on time, and emails group members to make sure everything is done properly. I don't feel like the words 'facilitator' and 'coordinator' work because it's not an official role, just a role this person kind of ends up acting as.

> Example: I ended up acting as a ______ to help keep our group in tiptop shape.

Comment: *taskmaster* - "a person who supervises rigorously the work of others" (Dictionary.com)

Comment: I don't feel like 'taskmaster' would work because this person is not a supervisor or authority figure to the group at all, but is instead an equal member of the group that ends up adopting a role to help keep the group in tiptop shape.

Comment: These duties are often assigned to a *team leader* in US businesses, though that term also tends to be "official".

Comment: *de facto leader*

Comment: For [tag:single-word-requests] you must include an example sentence. Can you add one?

Comment: Here are [50 synonyms for leader](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-synonyms-for-leader/). I couldn't find one that seemed to fit, but perhaps you can.

Comment: You can always be a *self-appointed taskmaster*.

Comment: De facto supervisor.

Comment: How is this different from a [*project manager*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_manager)?

Comment: Project manager, leader, taskmaster, drill sergeant, all of these things imply rank or official roles. If you're talking to anybody who isn't smugly proud of hating sports I would use point-guard.

Comment: And though that's an official role on a team, you can couch it without sounding like an idiot. "Bob is sort of our point guard..." sounds smart and flattering to Bob. "Bob is sort of our project manager" sounds like your business is either incompetently structured or like you're taking Bob down a peg for being a terrible PM.

Comment: I might suggest [community organizer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/community_organizer)

Comment: "I ended up acting as a" - already implies that this is not an official role, since the person is only "acting as". So even if an _official_ term is used after this, it would imply an _unofficial_ role IMO.

Answer (score 6):

If the person you described is well liked among the group members, you could call him or her a self-appointed administrator.

> I ended up acting as a self-appointed administrator in order to help keep our group in tiptop shape.

If the person is not well liked among the group members, I guess you could call him or her a self-appointed ramrod, a ramrod being a strict taskmaster or disciplinarian.

> I ended up acting as a ramrod who whipped our little group into shape.

Other possibilities with varying valences:

> - cheerleader
> - snoopervisor (my neologism)
> - busybody
> - organizer
> - proctor
> - monitor
> - checker
> - a jack of all trades (*trades* would be a kind of synonym for the various tasks you took upon yourself)
> - motivator
> - overseer
> - the responsible party
> - the go-to person
> - drill sergeant
> - de facto supervisor
> - volunteer

Comment: One a personal note, I'd wince if I heard someone describe themselves as a self-appointed administrator. Echoes of overbearing dictator/manager spring to mind.

Comment: Do you need the words "self-appointed" in that phrase when it is already prefixed with "I ended up acting as" - they would seem to be saying the same thing?

Comment: I'm not too sure about ramrod, it's not a word I've heard in any regular usage and especially in the context of 'whipping into shape' could be misconstrued...

Comment: @w3d: Good point. "Self-appointed" does seem redundant. Thanks. Don

Comment: @Paddy: I haven't heard "ramrod" in a long time. I seem to remember a TV show from my childhood ("Rawhide"), and actor Clint Eastwood played the character of "Rowdy Yates." Rowdy was the ramrod for Gil Favor, the character who was the boss of the cattle drive. Yes, "ramrod" could very well be misconstrued, and it definitely has a negative connotation! Don

Comment: @Vix: No argument there! Don

Answer (score 5):

This is not a single word, but you can minimally modify your context to fit it:

> ***[take (over/up) the reins](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+over+the+reins)***
>
> to take control of something, especially an organization or a country

Someone who takes the reins is usually not an official leader, but assumes an informal leadership role of their own accord.

In your context:

> I ended up *taking the reins* to help keep our group in tiptop shape.

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities, albeit not single words, are *de facto team leader* and *de facto supervisor*.

From Dictionary.com:

> [*de facto*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/de-facto?&o=100074&s=t):
>   in fact; in reality

For all intents and purposes, persons such as you describe are carrying out the role of team leader or supervisor. Even though they don't have this title officially, they act, and are treated by their coworkers, as if they did.

Of these possibilities, *de facto team leader* appears to fit best.

Your example:

> I ended up acting as a *de facto team leader* to help keep our group
>   in tiptop shape.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps ***[catalyst](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catalyst)***

2:  an agent that provokes or speeds significant change or action

> I ended up acting as a catalyst to help keep our group in tiptop
>   shape.

I think this would be a good choice if you are trying to avoid the implication of a leadership role.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ***[coach](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coach)*** or *unofficial coach* -- someone who provides direction, guidance and encouragement as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The single-word term you may be looking for in this case is *foreman*, *forewoman*, or *foreperson*.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/foreman

It's an official term (opposed to your connotation for "facilitator" and "coordinator") with uses in legal proceedings and general workplaces. A foreperson may be responsible for the well-being of a group, but also may have the same duties as other group members.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> I ended up playing the role of *project manager* to help keep our group on track.

or

> I ended up acting as a *housekeeper*, to help keep our group in tiptop shape.

Comment: To combine two answers - "de facto project manager"

Answer (score 1):

From sports, [*captain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_(sports)) (or *team captain*) might work. You're still a player on the team with the usual responsibilities, but you're also somewhat responsible for the overall team.

The analogy holds well because sports teams usually have a *coach* in an official role above the team.

Answer (score 1):

You could also end up acting as a [shepherd](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shepherd?s=t).

> 2. a person who protects, guides, or watches over a person or group of people.

(from dictionary.com, as linked).

Answer (score 0):

On the positive spin of https://english.stackexchange.com/a/353754/126251, I propose:

- [flag/standard] bearer

  > I ended up acting as the flag bearer to help keep our group in tiptop shape.

Figurehead being inspired from a bust you might mount on the front of a ship, 'a nominal leader or head without real power'. Has slight cynical connotations, best used with a slight smirk, rather tongue-in-cheek.

- figurehead

  > I ended up acting as a figurehead to help keep our group in tiptop shape.

Were it more along the lines of transformation:

- change agent

  > I ended up acting as a change agent in order to help our group excel.

In a humorous context:

- mascot

  > I took it upon myself to become the mascot of the group to help keep us in tiptop shape

And two which would be uncommon, though I would like to find an excuse to use:

- proponent (of change)
- reagent

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "point-guard" used a lot in business settings. It's not the most cultured as a sports metaphor, but it evokes leadership without elevated rank or any overbearing disposition--you're part of the team, sweating with the team, but directing its efforts.

Answer (score 0):

A facilitator is someone who engages in the activity of facilitation. They help a group of people understand their common objectives and assists them to plan how to achieve these objectives; in doing so, the facilitator remains "neutral" meaning he/she does not take a particular position in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Rather more poetic, and metaphorical than the other answers, but I might go for:

- Sheepdog ("act as the sheepdog to chase them up and keep them together")
- Glue ("act as the glue holding the team together")

?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! We strive to provide objective and well-researched answers. This answer needs to be expanded by providing evidence. Take the [Tour] and see [answer] for more.

Answer (score 0):

**Team leader**

Keep it simple.

Supporting info: [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_leader)

> A team leader is someone who provides guidance, instruction, direction and leadership to a group of other individuals (the team) for the purpose of achieving a key result or group of aligned results.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest phrase that fits in your sentence is simply "lead" or "leader". Though the person does not have that job title they are effectively fulfilling that role. For a given software development group that role might move from person to person among a group of peers for any given project.